# How to read and append text file based on certain conditions

Tags: java, file, text, append

What the program does: A user loads a file and it saves the file name, creation date and a file number to a text file. I want the program to check the file to see if the filename is already stored. If it is, to then check the creation date to see if it matches the one the user is currently trying to save. If it differs, to save over the currently saved creation date with the new one.

An example of Info.txt:

```
CreationDate: 140319, FileName: example1.txt, FileNumber: 1
CreationDate: 110219, FileName: example2.txt, FileNumber: 6
CreationDate: 100319, FileName: example3.txt, FileNumber: 14
```

How I create and write to the file:

```java
public void fileCreation() throws IOException {
    String fileinformation = File.creationdate + ", " + File.name + ", " + "Number: " + File.Number;

    FileWriter wr = new FileWriter("Info.txt", true);

    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(wr);
    output.println(fileinformation);
    output.close();
}
```

How I'm currently checking the file, at the moment it only prints the file contents, so if a User goes to save example2.txt with a different creation date, then the new one should overwrite the current one

```java
public void scanFile() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Info.txt"));
    String readfile;
    while ((readfile = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(readfile);
    }
    System.out.println("file not found");
}
```

Creation date is a long number and File.creationdate is a string such as "CreationDate: 140319", it would also be good to put a check to see if the FileNumber matches, but this is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should use split on your line with ',' as a separator.
Then you can go through every line and for each line check if first the name is the same as the file name, if it is, go and check the date and then finally check the FileNumber.
But why do you need to check it one by one ? Better to write it in with &&, like this

```
public boolean scanFile() throws IOException {
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Info.txt"));
String readfile;
Boolean isAlreadyIn = false;
while ((readfile = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] parts = readFile.split(',');
    if(parts[1].replace("FileName: ","").equals(File.name) &&parts[0].replace("CreationDate: ","").equals(File.creationdate) &&parts[2].replace("FileNumber: ","").equals(File.number){
      isAlreadyIn = true; // you can also write directly in this fonction
    }
    return isAlreadyIn;      
}
```

}

if you really need to check it one by one, just make a if(if( if()) with the condition in it